# Howto force TinyMCE to create SPAN tag inside of P tags?

Tags: javascript, html, tags, tinymce

i have to customize tinymce and have such problems with that... my problem is, that all default text should be wrapped within a span and p tag.

e.g.: `<p><span>My Text</span></p>`

if i will add formatting it should be changed to e.g.: `<p><span style="font-weight:bold;">My Text</span></p>`

tinymce should not remove the span or p tag if i will change the text or save the html output...

is such a scenario possible? has anybody a hint for me, to find the correct places in tinymce?

Answer (score 1):

Jesus this question has gone unanswered for a while. Don't know if you are still looking for an answer but the best approach is to find the config file for tinyMCE and add  to the list of accepted tags. I had to do this for frames and it worked fine!

Comment: +1 this is almost correct, there is still the problem to have all text wrapped in spans

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set the settings valid_children and valid_elements accordingly

```
    valid_elements: "@[id|class|title|style|onmouseover]," +
    "a[name|href|target|title|alt]," +
    "#p,blockquote,-ol,-ul,-li,br,img[src|height|width],-sub,-sup,-b,-i,-u," +
    "span,hr",

    valid_children: "body[p|ol|ul]" +
    ",p[a|span|b|i|u|sup|sub|img|hr|#text]" +
    ",span[p|a|b|i|u|sup|sub|img|#text]" +
    ",a[span|b|i|u|sup|sub|img|#text]" +
    ",b[span|a|i|u|sup|sub|img|#text]" +
    ",i[span|a|b|u|sup|sub|img|#text]" +
    ",sup[span|a|i|b|u|sub|img|#text]" +
    ",sub[span|a|i|b|u|sup|img|#text]" +
    ",li[span|a|b|i|u|sup|sub|img|ol|ul|#text]" +
    ",ol[li]" +
    ",ul[li]",
```

Second you will need to take care of the wrapping in spans yourself using the setup config parameter and a handler. The other option is to write an own plugin and handle this there.
Let me know if you are able to make it work. If not come back and ask.